# Circumflex accent before c IN LISP

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I'm studing lisp and I found this: (zoom in)^C ^C , but the text don't explain it, and I searched "^C ^C" in other places but didn't found anything. Can someone here help-me?

(I'm studying english yet, sorry if I wrote anything wrong)

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the C programming language?

Comment: @Praetorian nice catch :)  Removed the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"^C^C" is not AutoLisp; that would be for/is the macro language for menus and such.

Caret-C does "mean" CTRL-C.

What it does in the macro language:

```
^c means: cancel
^c^c means: cancel twice.
```

In AutoCAD we hit the ESC key (twice to cancel a command). The ^C^C is "good practice". -i.e. Before we issue or start a new command we cancel any current command.

The equivalent in AutoLisp would be:

```
(command) (command)
```

or

```
(repeat 2 (command))
```

Comment: I'm very good answer, and u saw the tags i've used, the others didn't do it, so the acepter anser go for u.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think they refer to the control-character ctrl-c you enter after entering `(zoom in)` in the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, most likely it means Ctrl+C, especially if you're using emacs, where two Ctrl+C presses (usually written "C-c C-c" in the emacs convention, though) means "run this using the default interpreter" in some language modes.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, `^C` usually represents the "Ctrl+C" modified keypress.

It won't work in a console on Windows, as Ctrl+C also means "break (execution)", but if you press Ctrl+V, Ctrl+P, etc., you'll see what I mean.